# Setting up pyCharm pro for remote ssh

Tags: ssh, pycharm, remote-access

I have PyCharm pro and I need to set up a remote repo on it via ssh. There are instructions available for doing this but my requirements are slightly different than what I have seen available. My organisation has ssh set up via cloudfare and all those configs are already put in `.ssh/config`. It includes hostname, IdentityFile, username, and so on. If I need to access my remote machine, I just do `ssh <HOST-NAME>` from the terminal.  My config looks like this -

```
Host <HOST-NAME>
    HostName <HOST-NAME>.<ORGANISATION>.net
    ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/cloudflared access ssh --hostname %h
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User <USER-NAME>
```

The way to set up PyCharm usually includes instructions like specifying host, port, username etc so that PyCharm can essentially run
`ssh username@host_ip_address`. However, I just need it to run `ssh <HOST-NAME>` so that it can access everything else using the config file that is already set up.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I use Pycharm Pro with my own .ssh/config and Jump Proxy pseudo hostname and certificates so slightly different. I "ssh pseudo-hostname" so no user as well.
In Pycharm I set a valid username and port (default 22) cause in my case it will get passed on.

Your setup ignore username and port no? If so you can use BS values?